# Como hacer consultas SQL de frecuencia por hora y por jornada?

Tags: sql

Quiero saber cuando esta mi aplicación el más utilizado por hora y por jornada con fines comparativos para la comercialización. Puedo hacerlo con la base de datos PostgreSQL pero el problema esta que no sé como segmentar los resultados por hora y por dia.

Tengo dos tablas : `swipe` y `eclipse_hastag`:

Aqui está la tabla `eclipse_hastag`:

[image: base de datos eclipse_hastag]

Aqui esta la tabla `swipe`:
[image: base de datos swipe]

Como conocer cuantas veces tenemos `swipe.state=3, 6 o 9` por horas por semanas ordenado en forma decreciente ?

Answer (score 2):

por lo que entiendo, solo es necesaria la segunda tabla.
Esta consulta contaría los subscriber_id por día de la semana (lunes, martes... etc)

```
select count(subscriber_id) as total, to_char(date, 'W') as week_day from swipe
where state in (3,6,9)
group by to_char(date, 'W') 
order by count(subscriber_id) desc
```

Para agrupar y contar por otra hora/fecha, sustituye la 'W' que representa el dia de la semana por cualquier otro valor de esta lista:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-formatting.html